# Port Forwarding on ZTE modem doesn't works

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat

Modem Type : **ZTE ZXHN H108N**

I am trying to set port-forwarding from my modem to my CCTV. My CCTV configuration is as below:

```
IP Address : 192.168.1.160
Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0
Gateway : 192.168.1.254
HTTP Port : 80
```

My modem configuration IP Address is 192.168.1.254. I tried set the config on modem as below:

[image]

```
Protocol - all
Starting port - 80
End port - 80
Local IP - 192.168.1.160
```

Also with DMZ :

[image]

However when I browse [public_ip], it shows the modem configuration page (as image above). When I tried to change the Port, it can't access the page at all. Also already set the DDNS using DynDns, but still accessing the modem configuration page. When I tried directly access the CCTV IP, it showing. What's wrong? Thanks..

Comment: You need to disable configuration of your modem from outside your local network.

Comment: @DavidPostill How to do that?

Comment: Read the manual or ask your ISP.

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 How about setting up a NAT rule instead in your router and tell it to send anything inbound for that specific TCP port to send that over to your CCTV LAN address (192.168.1.160). This way when you come into the gateway's public IP address it will NAT the traffic over to the IP of the internal LAN .160 for accessing the CCTV streams,etc. I'd just disable DMZ and use NAT rules rather than port forwarding and be sure to put the specific public IP to the specific private on the correct TCP port.

Answer (score 2):

First, an advice: Turn the DMZ off before your network gets infected by an
attack coming from the Internet.
The modem acts as a hardware firewall, and DMZ just bypasses all the protections. For security, you should also disable access from the Internet to
the router's configuration page, and change the router's default password.

If I understand right, you are trying to access the CCTV from outside your network.

First remark: You cannot access from inside your local network a device on
this same network through the Internet, because the modem most probably does
not support back-loops. You should do such accesses from outside the network,
for example from your phone when not connected via the modem,
but not from your desktop.

The [manual for the ZXHN H108N](http://m.setuprouter.com/router/zte/zxhn-h108n/manual-2050.pdf) describes port forwarding on page 4-11:

Select **Advanced > Port Forwarding** to display the PORT FORWARDING page:

[image: port forwarding]

Now click **Add** and add parameters. As I do not have your router,
I cannot tell what the values are for all the parameters,
but here are some hints :

- Server IP Address : 192.168.1.160
- External Port Start/End : This is the port number you use with the modem.
  Choose a non-standard number, for example 1234,
  to avoid an Internet attack targeting well-known ports.
- Internal Port Start/End : The CCTV port number (80?)

To access the CCTV page from outside your network, use a URL of the
following format :

```
http://[public_ip]:1234/
```

Port 1234 will then be forwarded to the CCTV port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Your router is overriding the DMZ on port 80

Try changing the source port on the port forward rule to another port (8080) but leave the destination port the same (80)

You then should be able to connect to your CCTV

```
http://externalip:8080
```